# How do I increase the margin top and left on each image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, each

I have some text before some images. I want to achieve a cascade effect on a variable number of images much like in this picture bellow. [image: Intended result]
I don't know how many images there will be in the end so for now I have three. I also don't know the exact height and width but for now I have set it to 300 x 500px; I am trying to use jquery to style the images but so far I can only apply the same margins to all images. I believe that what I need is a loop than runs through each image, then adds 50px to the margin variables, then passes on to the next image using the new margin variable, then adds another 50px to the margin variables and so on...

To simply put it: Do you know how I can increase the margins as I pass through each image?
What would be the cleanest way of doing this?

This is my code:

```js
function cascade() {
 $('.journal-single-img').each(function(){
  var marginLeft = 50;
        var marginTop = 100;
   $(this).css({
   left:marginLeft,
            top:marginTop    
     });
            marginLeft= marginLeft + 50;
            marginTop= marginTop + 50;
 });
  }
 cascade()
```

```css
 img.journal-single-img {
 position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p>Aenean vel aliquet orci, et dapibus purus. Etiam fringilla neque vitae est condimentum, porta elementum nulla tincidunt. Morbi posuere odio lectus. 
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tumblr_oesiqbS7jo1sbdxw4o1_1280_red.jpg">
      <img class="journal-single-img" src="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tumblr_oesiqbS7jo1sbdxw4o1_1280_red.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="500" >
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Christies1_red.jpg"> 
      <img class="journal-single-img" src="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Christies1_red.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="500">
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tumblr_oja76fgsbR1qdsqp6o1_500_red.jpg">
      <img src="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tumblr_oja76fgsbR1qdsqp6o1_500_red.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="500" class="journal-single-img">
    </a>
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use index inside of your .each function, the code looks much cleaner.  Additionally, the way how you programmed that portion just kept on resetting marginLeft and marginTop. I rewrote it and added a container div to make the code function smoother:

```js
function cascade() {
 $('.journal-single-img').each(function(index){
  var marginLeft = 50;
    var marginTop = 100;
   $(this).css({
   left:marginLeft*index,
      top:marginTop*index    
   });
 });
  }
 cascade()
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}

img.journal-single-img {
 position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p>Aenean vel aliquet orci, et dapibus purus. Etiam fringilla neque vitae est condimentum, porta elementum nulla tincidunt. Morbi posuere odio lectus. 
  </p>
  <div class="container">
  <p>
    <a href="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tumblr_oesiqbS7jo1sbdxw4o1_1280_red.jpg">
      <img class="journal-single-img" src="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tumblr_oesiqbS7jo1sbdxw4o1_1280_red.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="500" >
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Christies1_red.jpg"> 
      <img class="journal-single-img" src="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Christies1_red.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="500">
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tumblr_oja76fgsbR1qdsqp6o1_500_red.jpg">
      <img src="http://jadepalacecollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tumblr_oja76fgsbR1qdsqp6o1_500_red.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="500" class="journal-single-img">
    </a>
  </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently resetting your `marginLeft` and `marginTop` each time you go through your each loop, if you move those variables out into the original function you'll not reset and instead iterate on them which will allow your cascade effect:

```
function cascade() {
    var marginLeft = 50;
    var marginTop = 100;
    $('.journal-single-img').each(function(){
      $(this).css({
        left: marginLeft,
        top: marginTop
      });
      marginLeft = marginLeft + 50;
      marginTop = marginTop + 50;
    });
}

cascade()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define variables before loop.

```js
    function cascade() {

        var marginLeft = 50;
        var marginTop = 50;


        $('.journal-single-img').each(function(){

            $(this).css({
                left:marginLeft,
                top:marginTop
            });

            marginLeft = marginLeft + 50;
            marginTop = marginTop + 50;
        });
    }

    cascade();
```